# Issues with giving Homebrew chown -R permissions

Tags: macos, permissions, homebrew, system

I had a permission problem with installing some libraries via Homebrew, and I found a fix on the internet: run the command `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`.

Now I am getting skeptical, did I give too many permissions to Homebrew? If so, how can I take it back?

Comment: Do you know what that does? Have you e.g. run `whoami`, run `brew --prefix`, read `man chown` to find out what `-R` does?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, good point. I did check that, and chown makes my `/usr/local` directory owned by Homebrew, and I was worried if it can have any ramifications?

Comment: *"makes my `/usr/local` owned by Homebrew"* - no, it doesn't. `whoami` is *you*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ooh, this makes sense! Right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` makes *the user* the owner of the directory, thus Homebrew does not have sudo rights and there should not be any issues with it.